# How to make the HTML5 video responsive?

Tags: html, video, slider

I never had been working with HTML5 video before. I want to be able to set the video to 100% width and it will remained 100% if the browser size had changed. But, it seems not working properly. I tested it on other browser, most of them looks wrong to me.

I was wondering if you can help me out?

http://www.blackwellautomation.ca

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

atry this;

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <video id="thevideo" controls preload="auto">
       <source src="thevideofile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="thevideofile.webm" type="video/webm">
   </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container video {
    height: auto !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    }
```

If the video is an embed in an iFrame (YouTube, Vimeo etc.) you will need to adopt a different approach - see: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos